# getting hyperlink from database to a sheet in excel

Tags: sql, vba, excel, hyperlink

I am new to excel ..... well i have 2 excel sheets one as a database and another to display the result based on some selection

```
enter code here
//for database connectivity

Option Explicit
Public cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Public rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Public strSQL As String

Public Sub OpenDB()
If cnn.State = adStateOpen Then cnn.Close
cnn.ConnectionString =
"Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};DBQ=" & _
ActiveWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & ActiveWorkbook.Name
cnn.Open
End Sub

Public Sub closeRS()
If rs.State = adStateOpen Then rs.Close
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
End Sub


// code to display on another sheet
Private Sub cmdReset_Click()
'clear the data
ComboBox1.Clear
ComboBox2.Clear
ComboBox3.Clear
Sheets("View").Visible = True
Sheets("View").Select
Range("dataSet").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).ClearContents
End Sub

Private Sub cmdShowData_Click()
'populate data
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [data$] WHERE "
If ComboBox1.Text <> "" Then
strSQL = strSQL & " [Product]='" & ComboBox1.Text & "'"
End If

If ComboBox2.Text <> "" Then
If ComboBox1.Text <> "" Then
strSQL = strSQL & " AND [Region]='" & ComboBox2.Text & "'"
Else
strSQL = strSQL & " [Region]='" & ComboBox2.Text & "'"
End If
End If

If ComboBox3.Text <> "" Then
If ComboBox1.Text <> "" Or ComboBox2.Text <> "" Then
strSQL = strSQL & " AND [Customer Type]='" & ComboBox3.Text & "'"
Else
strSQL = strSQL & " [Customer Type]='" & ComboBox3.Text & "'"
End If
End If

If ComboBox1.Text <> "" Or ComboBox2.Text <> "" Or ComboBox3.Text <> "" Then
'now extract data
closeRS
OpenDB
rs.Open strSQL, cnn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
Sheets("View").Visible = True
Sheets("View").Select
Range("dataSet").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).ClearContents
'Now putting the data on the sheet
ActiveCell.CopyFromRecordset rs
Else
MsgBox"I was not able to find any matching records.",vbExclamation+ vbOKOnly
Exit Sub
End If
closeRS
OpenDB

rs.Open strSQL, cnn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
Range("L6").CopyFromRecordset rs
Else
Range("L6:M7").Clear
MsgBox "There was some issue getting the totals.", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly
Exit Sub
End If
End If
End If
End Sub
Private Sub ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()
Dim v, e
With Sheets("data").Range("b2:b15")
v = .Value
End With
With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
.comparemode = 1
For Each e In v
    If Not .exists(e) Then .Add e, Nothing
Next
If .Count Then Me.ComboBox1.List = Application.Transpose(.keys)
End With
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox2_DropButtonClick()
Dim v, e
With Sheets("data").Range("c2:c15")
v = .Value
End With
With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
.comparemode = 1
For Each e In v
    If Not .exists(e) Then .Add e, Nothing
Next
If .Count Then Me.ComboBox2.List = Application.Transpose(.keys)
End With
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox3_DropButtonClick()
Dim v, e
With Sheets("data").Range("d2:d15")
v = .Value
End With
With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
.comparemode = 1
For Each e In v
If Not .exists(e) Then .Add e, Nothing
Next
If .Count Then Me.ComboBox3.List = Application.Transpose(.keys)
End With
End Sub
```

and snapshot to get better view 
[displaying sheet][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWBoJ.jpg
[input sheet with hyperlinks][2]  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYF3K.jpg
now the problem is I want to create a hyperlink on input sheet so that when the data is displayed in output sheet the hyperlink also displayed

also these 2 sheets are in same workbook 
  Thanks everyone in advance

Answer (score 0):

edited after further explanation of OP about hyperlinks

as for your very question ("How to create a hyperlink on input sheet") you just have to copy web addresses from any source (web browser, list,...), paste them in your data sheet proper column and assure that "dataSet" range in "View" sheet is wide enough to enclose this column (from screenshots it would likely be some "Sheets("View").Range("A2:E2")")

besides that I must admit I didn't know about the existence of this ADODB connection (and many others, as now I got to know) to handle worksheet data. So I studied your code and came up to one of its possible refactorings that I hope you don't mind I'm posting here

```
Option Explicit

'they all seem like module level variables -> no need to declare them "Public"
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

' some more useful module level variables
Dim viewSht As Worksheet, dataSht As Worksheet
Dim dataSetRng As Range


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

'set module level variables -> they'll be used throughout this module by other subs/funcs
Set viewSht = Sheets("View")
Set dataSht = Sheets("Data")
Set dataSetRng = viewSht.Range("dataSet")

'fill comboboxes -> no need to fill them everytime you click a combobox
Call FillComboBox(Me.ComboBox1, dataSht.Range("b2:b15"))
Call FillComboBox(Me.ComboBox2, dataSht.Range("c2:c15"))
Call FillComboBox(Me.ComboBox3, dataSht.Range("d2:d15"))

viewSht.Activate '<<<== activate your view sheet once for all

End Sub


' code to display on another sheet
Private Sub cmdReset_Click()

Range(dataSetRng, dataSetRng.End(xlDown)).ClearContents

End Sub


Private Sub cmdShowData_Click()
Dim strSQL As String

'populate data

'build strSQL
Call SetStrSQL(strSQL, ComboBox1.text, "Product")
Call SetStrSQL(strSQL, ComboBox2.text, "Region")
Call SetStrSQL(strSQL, ComboBox3.text, "Customer Type")

'try and write data only if strSQL has been built
If Len(strSQL) >= 0 Then
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [data$] WHERE " & strSQL
    'now extract data
    closeRS
    OpenDB
    rs.Open strSQL, cnn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
    If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
        With dataSetRng
            Range(.Cells, .End(xlDown)).ClearContents
            'Now putting the data on the sheet
            .CopyFromRecordset rs
            Call SetHyperLink(.CurrentRegion.Columns(5))
            .EntireColumn.AutoFit
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "I was not able to find any matching records.", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If
    closeRS
End If

End Sub


Public Sub SetHyperLink(rng As Range)
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In rng.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
   rng.Parent.Hyperlinks.Add cell, cell.Value, , , cell.Value
Next cell
End Sub


Private Sub SetStrSQL(strSQL As String, cbText As String, field As String)

If cbText <> "" Then strSQL = strSQL & IIf(Len(strSQL) = 0, "", " AND") & " [" & field & "]='" & cbText & "'"

End Sub


Private Sub FillComboBox(Cb As ComboBox, dataRng As Range)
Dim v, e

v = dataRng.Value
With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    .CompareMode = 1

    'instead of checking for every element in dictionary, it's faster to try and add element: duplicates will be automatically discharged
    On Error Resume Next '<<< to prevent possible errors thrown by duplicates from stopping the macro
    For Each e In v
        .Add e, Nothing
    Next
    On Error GoTo 0 ' <<< enable error trapping

    If .Count Then Cb.list = Application.Transpose(.Keys)
End With

End Sub
'-------------------------------


'-------------------------------
'ADODB handling code
' as for this block of code I'm just learning from you it exists
' I feel like it could be enhanced but don't know how

Private Sub OpenDB()

CloseDB
cnn.ConnectionString = "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};DBQ=" & _
ActiveWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & ActiveWorkbook.Name
cnn.Open

End Sub


Private Sub CloseDB()

If cnn.State = adStateOpen Then cnn.Close

End Sub


Private Sub closeRS()

If rs.State = adStateOpen Then rs.Close
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient

End Sub
```

I see it gets visualized with quite strange an editing, but I don't know how to fix it!

Comment: thank you @user3598756 for suggestions i will definitely try to improve ..... but as you by now have got an idea that i am using  sheet(data) as input databse and sheet(View)to display based on some choices made from combobox so dataset(output cells) come automatically AND ARE NOT FIXED so what i want if i could add hyperlink on sheet(data) and when i display it on sheet(View) it could be displayed with the hyperlink

Comment: see edited code. just added a `SetHyperLink` sub and a call to it right after `.CopyFromRecordset rs`

Comment: it gives compiler error " invalid or unqualified reference"

Comment: Too little clues to help you. My code was tested so you're likely to have some typos. Step through your code and point out the offending statement.

Comment: i had simply copied and checked it 10 times it gives same error o0

Comment: I mean step through your code during debugging. You may place cursor inside the main sub code and press F8 as many times as needed to reach the offending statement. or place a breakpoint at the first valid statement of any private sub in your userform code module (just place cursor inside each statement and press F9), have macro run and stop at every breakpoint from where you would press F8 to step statement by statement until the offending line. at every step you can hover the mouse over any variable reference to check its value or query it (or any expression) in the immediate window.

Comment: thanks for the efforts you putting in ........... but compilation still exits on this line                                                                                                         Call SetHyperLink(.CurrentRegion.Columns(5))

Comment: so first try to comment that line and see if everything works. assuming it will, then step through the code of `Sub SetHyperLink` to see which line actually throws an error and there you can query all involved variable status/value to get the main clue to lead you to the actual culprit, that could also be tracked back up to the caller sub (should, for instance, you found that `rng` passed to `SetHyperLink` is `Nothing`). And sInce it's a veeery short sub, it'll take you very little time to do that.

Comment: could seem like `dataSetRng` is not set or set to `Nothing`. And `dataSetRng` is set by the initial `Set dataSetRng = viewSht.Range("dataSet")` statement. so may be either you don't have any "named range" named "dataSet" in `viewSht` or `viewSht` is not set or set to `Nothing`. In the former case you must set a "named range" named "dataSet" in `viewSht`. In the latter case, since `viewSht` is set in `Set viewSht = Sheets("View")` statement, you must ensure you both have a sheet named "view" in the **active** sheet and the active sheet is the one you need!

Comment: the error is basically is on .CurrentRegion and if i remove that it is on .columns hope we both are on the same page also im bit confused in this statement 'Call SetHyperLink(.CurrentRegion.Columns(5))......' why it is 5

Comment: as for the `.CurrentRegion` and `.Columns` error placing, the "being on the same page" and the "why is it 5". In addition to my last comment issued I missed to tell you what cells must be referred by the "dataSet"  named range that must be set in your "View" sheet: they are the cells of the first database record after the headings. As per your screenshot these cells are "A2:E2", being "A1:E1" filled with the headings and column "E" the one with the website link field. and column "E" is the 5th column.... Sorry for not pointing that out from the beginning.

Comment: sorry for the delay and thankx for the continuous efforts ..... and details u gave were very helpful but i don't know why the same error is still persisting ..... and sorry i should have added that information myself 1)there are two sheets a) data b) view , 2)in the sheet, data, i have database and in the sheet ,View, as shown above i have form having 3 combobox and cell range from b13:e13 is named as "dataSet" which is used to display the data ..... important thing now "Are you not getting the above error" thank you again

Comment: I never had errors, otherwise I'd have told you. from your last explanations, you must have "dataset" named range refer to "B13:F13", so as to enclose column "F" (the 5th one) for a "Web Site" field. This latter field must be there in "data" sheet too. So the whole setup is: 1) in "data" sheet your data must span 5 columns, with the 5th column being the one with web hyper links. 2) in "view" sheet you must have a "dataset" named range span 5 columns with the 5th one being the one where web hyperlinks will be placed 3) in user form code set proper data range addresses in `UserForm_Initialize`

Comment: please the range(b13:e13) is "dataSet" moreover i want to mention it again  that the hyperlinks are on the sheet(data) column B (i.e. product column) refer to above pics [input sheet][2] [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/xrunW.jpg  so i don't think dataSet is required ..... more over can you give me your email id

Comment: sorry but it's not clear. you say that hyperlinks are on column B ("Product" column) of "data" sheet, but I don't see them in pic [input sheet][2] [2]. Maybe you should update the pic or post xls files

Comment: very well you can do that on your own ..... inserting hyperlink on column B anyhow i have done it as per request .....